# Disable native context menu in react native gifted chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

In my `react-native-gifted-chat` application I want to use my custom context menu when long pressing message bubble. So I use `react-native-context-menu-view` like below.

```js
const ChatContextMenu = ({bubbleProps}: Props) => {
    
    return (
        <ContextMenu
            actions={[{title: 'Delete'}]}
            onPress={(event) => {
                if (event.nativeEvent.name === 'Delete') {
                    console.log('deleting...')
                }
            }}
        >
            <Bubble
                {...bubbleProps}
            />
        </ContextMenu>
    )
}
```

And it works but when I long press the bubble, also the native context menu appears like in the photo below

[image]

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<GiftedChat
  onLongPress={()=> {}}
```

Comment: hah, what a simple solution. Works perfect, thank you so much :)